# Kubernetes PHP NGINX Pods Intercommunication

Tags: kubernetes

I'm running a 3-master and 3-worker cluster, trying to communicate pods from php-fpm service with pods from nginx-service, have changed even CNI from Calico to Weave but the problem persists, any help would be great. Inside my nginx config I have:

```
            location ~ \.php$ {
            root           /var/www/html;
            fastcgi_pass   php:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        }
```

So I expect to get php-fpm service by name "php:9000". And here is my deployments and services cfg:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: web
  replicas: 9
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web
        image: docker-registry.vetorial.net/gponapi-nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web
  labels:
    component: web
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    component: web
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: php
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: php
  replicas: 9
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: php
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: php
        image: docker-registry.vetorial.net/gponapi-php
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: php
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: php
  ports:
  - port: 9000
    targetPort: 9000
```

And the error that I`m geting:

```
2019/12/21 12:54:25 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "php" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:52
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "php" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:52
```

There is something wrong with my deployments and services cfg?

EDIT:

Trying to debug DNS I see that pods are trying to resolve names in inherited DNS from host:

```
[ root@k8-master-01  >  ~/gponApi ] kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10

[ root@k8-master-01  >  ~/gponApi ] for p in $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name); do kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $p; done
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = 4e235fcc3696966e76816bcd9034ebc7
CoreDNS-1.6.5
linux/amd64, go1.13.4, c2fd1b2
[INFO] Reloading
[INFO] plugin/health: Going into lameduck mode for 5s
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = a4809ab99f6713c362194263016e6fac
[INFO] Reloading complete
[INFO] 127.0.0.1:60092 - 22335 "HINFO IN 6654671708538411669.1329448889047522534. udp 57 false 512" NOERROR - 0 4.001984467s
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 6654671708538411669.1329448889047522534. HINFO: read udp 10.32.0.4:37293->187.86.128.99:53: read: no route to host
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but it sounds like you are trying to run PHP-FPM separately from nginx. I don't think this is the correct approach with Kubernetes. I would rather suggest you have a container that is able to run your PHP application in on pod and your expose this with a service. If you need PHP-FPM + Nginx then it would be in that one container

Comment: Yes, I think it would be easier run everything in one pod but I'm trying to learn how kubernetes work, that's why I asked if there's an error in my config files, it appears that nginx pods can't reach php pods through the service so I'm trying to understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was firewalld, after disabling it everything works as expected.